# The People OOTB Webpart changes the Account name after page refresh SharePoint on-premise 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, people-picker, 2019, sharepoint-ootb

The URL for fetching the user profile picture changes after page refresh. The Account name is changed.

URL when new user is added to web-part:

```
http://your.xyz.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname=xyz\john
```

After page refresh the URL changes to:

```
http://your.xyz.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname=john@xyz.com
```

Comment: Is it causing any issue? are you able to see the profile picture after URL changes? Generally you can get the profile picture of user using URL like: `https://<your site url>/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname=<user email address>`.

Comment: I want to use account name only and not email. The picture are not showing when i use the email.